# Geometrical Isomerism (Cis-Trans) in trans-2-fluoro-3-methylpent-2-ene

Tags: organic-chemistry, cis-trans-isomerism

trans-2-fluoro-3-methylpent-2-ene this compound in also known as (Z)2-fluoro-3-methylpent-2-ene. 
I have given my possible structure in the image but it is wrong, Can anyone explain this ?

[image: My possible structure]

Comment: Just a guess but since the fluro and methyl are the named sidegroups, shouldn't the trans apply to their orientation to one another?

Comment: @bpedit it might be true, but it doesn't seem convincing enough. My general perception about trans structure remains that it should be symmetrical in some way. If they actually were side groups then how many more typed of side groups are there in organic ?

Comment: The implication of my suggestion is that the "-2-fluoro" should be on the bottom in your diagram so it is trans to the "-3-methyl" group. I'm no expert on the rules but it appears to make sense,

Comment: @bpedit I got your point, but why are we doing that shouldn't same groups be on opposite side in trans structures if the two same type of groups are present, isnt that the basic definition ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The structure you drew

[image]

is ‒ according to the [CIP-rules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cahn%E2%80%93Ingold%E2%80%93Prelog_priority_rules) ‒ (*E*)-configured.  These rules are applied on *each* side of the double bond; namely

- C of the ethyl group has a higher priority than C of the methyl group
- F has a higher priority than C
- C(ethyl group) opposes F, as seen across the double bond

This is *not* in contradiction that the two methyl groups are opposing each other, are in (*trans*)-relationship with each other.

In instances with only two subsitutents around a double bond, like (*E*)-2-pentene, you may use (*E*), derived from German "entgegen", literally "opposing", as synonym to (*cis*).  For the opposite instance, (*Z*), derived from German "zusammen", like "together", to describe a (*trans*)-configuration.

In instances with three or four substitutions around a double bond, and instances of several conjugated double bonds, follow IUPAC and adhere to the (*E*/*Z*) notation; which is absolute and not ‒ as (*cis*/*trans*) ‒ relative and potentially ambiguous.  See the example [*E*/*Z* notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cis%E2%80%93trans_isomerism), for example. (Or, as one teacher told me, "stay on the E-Z pass".)

Comment: I know that when 3-4 subsitutions around a double are present, we follow CIP rules. But suppose this compound was given to you as (Z) confirguration and asked whether it will trans or cis then how will you account for that ?

Comment: @Aviral Agarwal The system of (*cis*)/(*trans*) works differently as the more general absolute, based on CIP rules.  Hence there might be confusions if applying the former in the instance of three / four times substituted alkenes (see the example in the link).  While *cis* corresponds to *Z* for simple cases of twice substituted dienes, this is no longer *every time* true for three and four times substituted dienes.  IUPAC even *discourages* deployment of (*cis*)/(*trans*), as in the Gold book: http://goldbook.iupac.org/html/C/C01092.html