# Difficulty in cis, trans isomers in Alkene

Tags: organic-chemistry, isomers

I have a difficulty in appointing cis trans isomer to an Alkene compound .

I have looked it up and drawn out a few -

[image]

[image]

[image]

Which "point" should I look at to understand in order to allocate cis and trans ? I know it's between the first and last line . Thanks!

Comment: The last name is wrong. There is no cis/trans isomerism because the two methyl groups are identical.

Answer (score 0):

You may think of the two lines representing the double bond like the bird's eye view on a door of a saloon:  If the two wings, the one on the left of the double bond, and the one of right flap in *the same* direction, then the double bond is in *cis*-configuration.  On the contrary, if the two flap in *opposing* directions, than the double bond is in *trans*-configuration.

For future reference -- taking into account the third picture shown by you -- *cis* and *trans* may be ambiguous; and triple and quadruple substituted double bonds' configuration are described *only* with *E*- or *Z*-configuration (cf. [here](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/71553/geometrical-isomerism-cis-trans-in-trans-2-fluoro-3-methylpent-2-ene/71560#71560)).  Eventually, as correctly pointed by @Zhe, in your last example, the double bond is neither *E*-, nor *Z*-configurated.